# IPv6 connection with DataSnap

Tags: ios, delphi, datasnap

At WWDC 2015 Apple announced the transition to IPv6-only network services in iOS 9. Starting June 1, 2016 all apps submitted to the App Store must support IPv6-only networking.

My Delphi IOS App have a IPv4 IP, im using a TDSRestConnection now in the Host property i set 2112:d8ac:64c4::d8bc:64c4 and say "error is socket error11004" if i use the IPv4 format all is fine.

How i make my IOS app use IPv6.

I'm Using XE8, Rest DataSnap Server

[image]

Comment: 11004 is `WSANO_DATA`, which is a hostname lookup error. Without knowing your DataSnap setup, your Delphi version, etc, I can only guess that your DataSnap is likely using an IPv4 socket and thus cannot use an IPv6 address. In that case, it would consider an IPv6 address in the `Host` as a non-IPv4 address and try to resolve it as a hostname to an IPv4 address and fail. Your situation is the exact same as [QC #109002 Datasnap Driver not IPv6 compatible](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=109002), which was marked as fixed in XE4 (I don't know what the "fix" actually was).

Comment: I do know that in the latest Delphi version, Embarcadero has set their copy of Indy to IPv6-only on iOS.  I'm sure that carries through to DataSnap and other Embarcadero technologies that use Indy internally (I think they are slowing starting to migrate their technologies to their own `System.Net` classes and not use Indy anymore, though).

Comment: Thank Remy im using xe8 and a rest server Datasnap, i saw the #109002 report but dont say how resolve it, how can i set to Indy to use IPv6

Comment: How to set *Indy* to use IPv6 is fairly simple, most Indy components have an `IPVersion` property available that defaults to `Id_IPv4` but can be set to `Id_IPv6` instead.  How to set *DataSnap* to use IPv6, I have no clue.

Comment: yes that is the issue how force datasnap use Id_IPv6

Comment: I don't think you can, it is likely hard-coded inside of DataSnap's implementation, and AFAIK you cannot recompile DataSnap anyway.

Comment: TDSRestConnection has this property: `dsrestconnection1.HTTP.Peer.IPVersion` - no idea if it will fix your problem or not.  You can try setting it to `IP_IPv6`

Comment: ... just use domain name resolution ...

Comment: i set dsrestconnection1.HTTP.Peer.IPVersion :=IP_IPv6 ; in the datamodule module creation, now i got a host not found exception.

Comment: i make son test, my development pc dont show a IPv6, but the server where is hosted the rest datasnap server have IPv6 enabled, if i run the in my developent PC fail http://[2002:d8ac:64c4::d8ac:64c4]:105/datasnap/rest/TSM/GetImagenOfertaxIDs/12/0/0   but if i tun that in a PC that have a IPv6 run fine

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez how does DNS fix missing or misconfigured IPv6 support on the client side?