# Datasnap "network is unreachable" error over IPv6

Tags: ios, delphi, ipv6, delphi-xe8, datasnap

When I try to connect to a Datasnap REST server over an IPv6 network, I get a socket "network is unreachable" error.

I'm using `TDSRestConnection` to connect.  I have set my server name in the `HostName` property.

Comment: Known issue, see [IPv6 connection with DataSnap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37691084/) and [IPv6 Datasnap (IOS App)](http://community.embarcadero.com/answers/ipv6-datasnap-ios-app).

Answer (score -2):

The server side needs to add to its public DNS a register type AAAA. This is a DNS64 for IPv6. So, the value for this register is the Google NAT64 prefix (64:FF9B::) + your IPv4.

If the public IP for example is 200.123.12.34, the  AAAA register value will be 64:FF9B::200.123.12.34. R. Another value is your domain name like myapp.mydomain.com or myapp.mydomain.com.br. Other thing you need to do is implement a function to resolve the name when your Iphone is in a network with IPv6.

The above example doesn't work for REST DATASNAP CLIENTS. Below my example, I've implemented that on my datasnap client module.

```
const
  S_HOST_NAME = 'myapp.mydomain.com';

var
  control : integer;

implementation

procedure TfrmClientModule.conect;
var
  x : string;
begin
  try
    control := control + 1;
    if control < 3 then
    begin
      DSRestConnection.Reset;
      x := ServerMethods1Client.ReverseString('yx');
    end;
  except
    if DSRestConnection.Host = S_HOST_NAME then
      DSRestConnection.Host := '[' + S_HOST_NAME + ']'
    else
      DSRestConnection.Host := S_HOST_NAME;
    conect;
  end;
end;

procedure TfrmClientModule.DataModuleCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
    Controle := 0;
    DSRestConnection.Host :=  '[' + S_HOST_NAME + ']';
    conect;
end;
```

Comment: NO no no. DO NOT EVER put an RFC 6052 address in the public DNS as an AAAA record. This will _prevent_ IPv6 users from accessing your site via IPv6.

Comment: The question is a client side question. There's no guarantee that poster even has access to the server. You don't need to address 'everybody' just answer the question. Also when creating the answer press the help button in the toolbar above the text input window to learn how to format your text. The code looks horrible because you didn't indent it 4 spaces to put it in a code block. Doing that won't fix your answer technically or with regard to the question but you can see how it improves its readability.