# Delphi Datasnap connection error with IPv6 (iOS)

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey, ipv6, datasnap

We have an iOS and Android app that uses Datasnap to connect to end-user's datasnap Windows database servers from their mobiles/tablets. Everything was working fine, except now Apple rejects the new version of our app because *it is not IPv6 compatible*. Ok

Our Firemonkey mobile app (Delphi Seattle) lets end-users to set up **their own server configuration** (IP and Port). They must have a Windows PC server application running in **their own server**, so, there isn't any HOSTNAME. They just know their server Public IP address. The server application is installed in a simple Windows PC. Not a web server, domain, etc. so there isn't any server host-name, but an IP address.

After following Apple's instructions to create a IPv6 private shared network, the problem exists. I get "*Server Unreachable*" error when trying to connect to any **IP address** from my iPad.
I have read that using brackets [  ] with the *hostname* will work, but I can't get it. Maybe it only works with hostnames, not ip addresses?

Here is a simplified portion of code where I do the connection to the server:

Client side (mobile app):
- TSQLConnection (Datasnap Driver. Communication protocol: tcp/ip)
- TDSProviderConnection

```
    SQLConnection1.Params.Values['HostName'] := MY_SERVER_IP;
    try
        DSProviderConnection1.Connected:=true;
    except
        showmessage('error');
    end;
```

I have tried XX.XX.XX.XX and [XX.XX.XX.XX] values for MY_SERVER_IP with no success.
I don't know if I have to change something in the server's Windows application or just on client-side (mobile/firemonkey)

Any solution?

Comment: IP v6 is something like 2001:0db8:85a3:08d3:1319:8a2e:0370:7344 - no dots, not only four groups. Just enclosing a IP v4 address in brackets will not make it a valid IP v6 address. You need to know the IP v6 address of the server...

Comment: Use ipconfig (on the server) to find the IP v6 address of its network adapter for internal testing. For a public server, the network administrator should know its IP v6 adress

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37691084/ipv6-connection-with-datasnap

Answer (score 0):

I got it

I found a chinese forum with some tricks I haven't found before.

It is possible to configure the **Datasnap Communication IP version** with the following parameter:

```
TDBXDatasnapProperties(SQLConnection1.ConnectionData.Properties).CommunicationIPVersion
```

By default, if empty, it is IPv4.
So, on the *TSQLConnection.OnBeforeConnect* event, just added the following line:

```
// You need to know if you are on IPv4 or IPv6 first. I explain it later.

if ipversion='IPv4' then   
    TDBXDatasnapProperties(SQLConnection1.ConnectionData.Properties).CommunicationIPVersion:='IP_IPv4'
else
    TDBXDatasnapProperties(SQLConnection1.ConnectionData.Properties).CommunicationIPVersion:='IP_IPv6';
```

And that's all!! 
Of course, you need to know if you are on a IPv4 network or in a IPv6 one.
I do this with a *TidTcpClient* component. That component has a 'IPVersion' parameter you can set up.

So, first, try to connect using IPVersion:=Id_IPv4. If successful, you are on a IPv4 network. If not, then you probably are on a IPv6 network (or server is down). So...

```
    IdTCPClient1.IPVersion:=Id_IPv4;  // <--  try IPv4 first
    IdTCPClient1.Host:=MY_IP;
    try
        IdTCPClient1.Connect;
        result:=true;
        ipversion := 'IPv4';      // <-- will tell us what ip version to use
    except
    end;

    if IdTCPClient1.Connected=false then
    begin
        try
            IdTCPClient1.IPVersion:=Id_IPv6;  // <--  now try IPv6
            IdTCPClient1.Connect;
            result:=true;
            ipversion:='IPv6';    // <-- will tell us what ip version to use
        except
        end;
    end;
```

And that's all. Now the app works fine on both IPv4 and IPv6 from my iPad!

Comment: Since Apple is focusing on IPv6, I suggest you try connecting with IPv6 first and then fallback to IPv4, not the other way around. Also, have a look at Indy's `TidStack.GetLocalAddressList()` method, which can also tell you if you are connected to an IPv6 network without actually connecting to a server.